# Protein sequence pattern-matching python

Tags: python, algorithm, for-loop, pattern-matching, sequence

I'm working on a matching algorithm for protein sequences. I'm starting with an aligned protein sequence, and I am attempting to convert a mis-aligned sequence into the correctly aligned one. Here is an example:

original aligned sequence: ----AB--C-D-----

mis-aligned sequence: --A--BC---D-

The expected output should look like this:

original aligned sequence: ----AB--C-D-----

mis-aligned sequence: ----AB--C-D----- (both are now the same)

I'm told to be very specific about my problem, but the sequences I'm trying to match are >4000 characters long, and look ridiculous when pasted here. I'll post two sequences representative of my problem, though, and that should do.

```
seq="---A-A--AA---A--"
newseq="AA---A--A-----A-----"
seq=list(seq) #changing maaster sequence from string to list
newseq=list(newseq) #changing new sequence from string to list
n=len(seq) #obtaining length of master sequence
newseq.extend('.') #adding a tag to end of new sequence to account for terminal gaps

print(seq, newseq,n) #verification of sequences in list form and length

for i in range(n)
    if seq[i]!=newseq[i]:
        if seq[i] != '-': #gap deletion
            del newseq[i]

        elif newseq[i] != '-':
            newseq.insert(i,'-') #gap insertion


        elif newseq[i] == '-':
            del newseq[i]


old=''.join(seq) #changing list to string
new=''.join(newseq) #changing list to string
new=new.strip('.') #removing tag

print(old) #verification of master-sequence fidelity
print(new) #verification of matching sequence
```

The output I get from this particular code and set of sequences is:

---A-A--AA---A--

---A-A--A----A-----A-----

I can't seem to get the loop to correctly delete unwanted dashes in between the letters more than once, because the rest of the loop iterations are used in an add dash/delete dash pair.
This is a good start to the problems here.

How can I write this loop successfully to obtain my desired output (two identical sequences)

Comment: There is no loop in this code sample

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I guess I lost the loop command in the shuffle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your code and it is giving correct output now:

```
seq="----AB--C-D-----"
newseq="--A--BC---D-"
seq=list(seq) #changing maaster sequence from string to list
newseq=list(newseq) #changing new sequence from string to list
n=len(seq) #obtaining length of master sequence
newseq.extend('.') #adding a tag to end of new sequence to account for terminal gaps

print(seq, newseq,n) #verification of sequences in list form and length
for i in range(len(seq)):
    if seq[i]!=newseq[i]:
       if seq[i]=='-':
           newseq.insert(i,'-')

       elif newseq[i]=='-':
           newseq.insert(i,seq[i])
       else:
           newseq.insert(i,seq[i])

else:
    newseq=newseq[0:len(seq)]

old=''.join(seq) #changing list to string
new=''.join(newseq) #changing list to string
new=new.strip('.') #removing tag

print(old) #verification of master-sequence fidelity
print(new) #verification of matching sequence
```

**output:**

```
----AB--C-D-----
----AB--C-D-----
```

and for `AA---A--A-----A-----`:

```
---A-A--AA---A--
---A-A--AA---A--
```

Comment: This algorithm, as the previous one, does not consider the possible mismatch between specific positions, different size strings and has no backtracking if a better solution arises afterwards. Please consider looking into dynamic programming.

Comment: I will definitely pursue dynamic programming for future work. This code works in general for my immediate purposes, though (the sequences are always the same order, there is only one solution, and this code works for different size strings). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem of sequence alignment is well known and its solution is well described. For an introductory text, see the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment). The best solution I know involves Dynamic programming, and you can see an example implementation in Java at [this site](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-seqalign/index.html).